# removeAllObjects message able to remove added objects that are engaged in retain cycles with NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Following is a small snippet out of my main code where i'm having an issue related to retain cycle

```
[rootObj.completeLines addObject:line];
[line setContainingArray:rootObj.completeLines];
[rootObj.completeLines removeAllObjects];// the issue..
```

In the above snippet rootObj.completeLines is an NSMutableArray to which a 'Line' object has been added. containingArray is a strong type pointer/property. Clearly this forms a retain cycle between the NSMutableArray object and the 'Line' object..
  In the next line i pass the removeAllObjects message to the array.. My question is, how come this message be able to purge an object (Line in this case) which is engaged in a retain cycle with another object (the Array). Clearly i must be missing something crucial here. Pls assist..

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you expect `removeAllObjects` to break the retain cycle?

Comment: i would expect it if in actuality the internal id pointer of NSMutableArray  point to nil in the removeAllObjects method..Then the cycle would longer remain.. Of this i'm unsure. In the internal implementation of NSMutableArray, are the id pointers of type weak or strong? If they are weak then no chance of retain cycle formation at all.

Comment: NSArrays always keep a _strong_ reference to the objects they contain.

Comment: Right.. got it now..Thanx a ton.. I totally had misunderstood the removeAllObjects' inner workings. Now i got it.

Answer (score 1):

As @CrimsonChris notes in his comment, `-removeAllObjects` is behaving correctly by breaking the retain cycle. Your `rootObj.completeLines` array retains `line` only as long as `line` is a member of the array; when you remove it, the array gives up its strong reference to `line`, so the only remaining retain is from `line` to its `containingArray`. Since nothing (in your provided snippet) is retaining `line` anymore, it's free to be deallocated.

Comment: So that means the removeAllObjects method internally has its internal pointer (which previously must be pointing to Line) point to nil explicitly. Earlier i used to think that the id pointers that hold the added objects are of weak type.. But it seems this isn't true. Is it?

Comment: An NSArray holds a series of _references_. Those references are either in the array or they aren't.

Comment: What do u mean by the id pointers being 'either in the array or not in the array'.??Those id pointer of type strong are all ivars. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `containingArray` property, of the stored object, is `weak`, which should avoid the retain cycle:

```
@property (weak) NSMutableArray *containingArray;
```